# Threw an exception when the notifier tried to update its state error in flutter_riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am developing an app with flutter and I am using flutter_riverpod package for state managment. But I am getting an error.

I have 2 main widget inside my screen. These are "ReadTopBarW" widget and "ReadArticleW" widget.
I am getting datas with http post with futureprovider with riverpod. There is no problem so far.
My purpose is change the icon with a response value.
I am getting the value in "ReadArticleW" and I am writing the value for StateProvider. And I will watch the value in "ReadTopBarW".

This is my "ReadArticleW"

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:eem_flutter_app/services/get_one_article.dart';
import 'package:eem_flutter_app/widgets/read/shimmer_read_w.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final isSavedVider = StateProvider((_) => '');

class ReadArticleW extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ReadArticleW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final futureCatFacts = ref.watch(singleArticleFProvider);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: futureCatFacts.when(
        data: (datax) {
          final decodedData = json.decode(datax.body);
          final isSaved = decodedData[1].toString();
          ref.read(isSavedVider.notifier).state = isSaved;
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                decodedData[0]['articleTitle'].toString(),
              ),
              Image.network(
                  decodedData[0]['articleLImage'].toString()),
            ],
          );
        },
        error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
        loading: () => const ShimmerReadW(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This my "ReadTopBarW"

```
import 'package:eem_flutter_app/widgets/read/read_article_w.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


class ReadTopBarW extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ReadTopBarW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final x = ref.watch(isSavedVider);
    print(x);
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)),
        Row(
          children: const [
            "0" == "1"
                ?  Icon(Icons.bookmark_border)
                :  Icon(Icons.bookmark_outlined),
             SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
             Icon(Icons.ios_share),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is error text. The error is vscode red error that you know

```
Exception has occurred.
StateNotifierListenerError (At least listener of the StateNotifier Instance of 'StateController<String>' threw an exception
when the notifier tried to update its state.

The exceptions thrown are:

setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This UncontrolledProviderScope widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  UncontrolledProviderScope
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  ReadArticleW
```

Please focus on th isSavedVider because the problem is here. There is no problem in singleArticleProvider.

note:
I simplified the code to publish here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't update a `StateProvider` in the `build` method, the error is  coming from here:

```
     child: futureCatFacts.when(
        data: (datax) {
          final decodedData = json.decode(datax.body);
          final isSaved = decodedData[1].toString();
          ref.read(isSavedVider.notifier).state = isSaved;
```

What you can you is `watch` the `singleArticleFProvider` in `isSavedVider` and set the value from the extracted response, this way, when there is an update to the response, it `isSavedVider` gets the update value like so:

```
final isSavedVider = StateProvider((ref){
  final futureCatFacts = ref.watch(singleArticleFProvider);
  if(futureCatFacts is AsyncData){
      final decodedData = json.decode(futureCatFacts.value.body);
      final isSaved = decodedData[1].toString();
      return isSaved;
  }
  return "";
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late turn. I have looked your answer. But I don't understand excatly. I am very new on riverpod. May you explain a little more.

Comment: Hi @mesh...` ref.read(isSavedVider.notifier).state = isSaved;` in the `data` callback is basically like "Calling setState" in a build method and that throws the error you're getting.

Comment: So, instead of updating it in the `data` call back, I moved it to the provider itself. It watches the `singleArticleFProvider` which means it'll recall the provider when there's a change in `singleArticleFProvider`

Comment: But you only want to use the `singleArticleFProvider` when there is data..That's why I did the if statement and retuning `""` when there is no data.

Comment: So, just remove   `final decodedData = json.decode(datax.body);
          final isSaved = decodedData[1].toString();
          ref.read(isSavedVider.notifier).state = isSaved;`

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I paste your code but there is error like here: https://ibb.co/M5c13hJ.

Comment: No no, you're not putting my code in the data callback, just replace the `isSavedVider` you have up top with it.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i'm a little stupid. Should I change "final isSavedVider = StateProvider((_) => '');" code

Comment: I feel embarrassed for not understanding what you are saying and taking your time.

Comment: Yes, should should change "final isSavedVider = StateProvider((_) => '');" to "final isSavedVider = StateProvider((ref){
  final futureCatFacts = ref.watch(singleArticleFProvider);
  if(futureCatFacts is AsyncData){
      final decodedData = json.decode(futureCatFacts.value.body);
      final isSaved = decodedData[1].toString();
      return isSaved;
  }
  return "";
});"

Comment: And you shouldn't feel embarrassed, everyone is learning.

Comment: Hmm. I tried but I am getting similar error. https://ibb.co/2tcH1dc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247796/discussion-between-josteve-and-mesh).

Comment: ok I will be in chat